# Control what DataContentHandler to use for a MimeMessage attachment?

Tags: java, email-attachments, mime-message, javax.activation

I am creating an attachment to `MimeMessage` for a Tiff image with a byte array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
body.setContent(tiffByteArray, "image/tiff");
body.setDisposition("attachment");
body.setFileName(filename);
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(body);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties()));
message.setContent(multipart);
message.writeTo(out);
String mimeContent = out.toString();
```

This normally works.  The image is converted to a base64 string in the message.  However, at some point something on the system occurs and this piece of code starts using `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ImageDataContentHandler`.  This particular converted expects an `java.awt.Image` object as opposed to a byte array ([relevant source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/soap/ImageDataContentHandler.java#120)).  I get the following error:

> Unable to encode the image to a stream ImageDataContentHandler requires Image object, was given object of type class [B

I can see that you can set the `javax.activation.DataHandler` on the `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` and in the `DataHandler` you can set the `javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory`, but I'm not sure what to set it to.

Is there a way to force a byte array to be converted to a base64 encoded String regardless of the mime type?

Comment: I think I might have found the answer https://books.google.com/books?id=9NaYku1OY4cC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=DataContentHandlerFactory&source=bl&ots=wsqCxfRckN&sig=Q25vgayKlJhhNhRPEVYA07vHPBc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOjsiJ447OAhVFw4MKHWpVDWUQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=DataContentHandlerFactory&f=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`javax.mail` provides a `DataSource` implementation for bytes that you can explicitly use.

```
ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(tiffByteArray, "image/tiff");
DataHandler byteDataHandler = new DataHandler(dataSource);
body.setDataHandler(byteDataHandler);
body.setDisposition("attachment");
body.setFileName(filename);
```